# get position in array of dragged element javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I have a sortable list and I want to get the position of the object I dragged in my array. So I can pass it with **ajax** and store to my db, but I can't figure out how to do this with my `for` loop

Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var rootLimit = 8;
        $('ul.sortable').nestedSortable({
            handle: 'a',
            items: 'li',
            listType: 'ul',
            maxLevels: '3',
            toleranceElement: '> a',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                list = $(this).nestedSortable('toHierarchy', {
                    startDepthCount: 0
                });
                var page_id = ui.item.find('> a').attr('data-page-id');
                console.log(list);
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var index = $(this).index();
                    console.log(index);
                }
                $.post(
                    '/page/updatemenu/' + page_id, 
                    { list : list },
                    function (data) { }
                );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kNPHe/), thanks!

Comment: your jsfiddle is not working, looks like your missing a template library or something

Comment: It is unclear to me what data you're trying to send to your server. Can you rephrase your question, or add comments to your code to help me?

Comment: It looks like you have PHP code in your jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

in your update function,

```
$(ui.item).index()
```

gives you the position of your item;